# Testing a .mhtml file as a .t

Tags: perl, mason

I want to write a test that loads .mhtml in a .t file so I can test the embedded perl. The issue I'm having is that having loaded the source with File::Slurp, running $interp->exec($source) has HTML::Mason::Interp::load() trying to use the .mhtml as a filename which is suboptimal.

Is there are better way to this?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to be much help without a **lot** more information - like a runnable program that exhibits the problem - but have you looked at [HTML::Mason::Tests](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/HTML-Mason/lib/HTML/Mason/Tests.pm)?

Oh, and don't use File::Slurp. [It's very broken.](http://blogs.perl.org/users/leon_timmermans/2015/08/fileslurp-is-broken-and-wrong.html)

Comment: I know about File::Slurp, luckily within our use case it works. File::Slurper is on my radar.

I've looked at HTML::Mason::Tests. I've got code loading .mhtml but globals like $dbh are unset, set_global doesn't appear to work and I don't know why. Also the autohandler chain doesn't work as expected.

I've looked on the internet and github and I can't see examples of relatively complex code to cargo cult from. I'm parking this task. We're removing code from .mhtml files into modules as we work on it.